# Regex match the last instance of string

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am parsing out zip codes from address strings which are stored in a pandas column using regex. The zipcodes are 5 digits, however, there are building/unit numbers that are also 5 digits. So, I'd like the last instance of the match/search.

Here's my code:

```
# Function to search Zipcode from Address

def zipregex(address):
    
    zipre = re.search('(\d{5})([- ])?(\d{4})?', address)
    
    if zipre:
    
        print(address, zipre.groups())

# Function call
df['Zip'] = df.apply(lambda x: zipregex(x['Address']), axis=1)
```

returns,

```
642b N 17th Ave, Phoenix, AZ 85007, USA ('85007', None, None)
38956-38962 N New River Rd, Peoria, AZ 85383, USA ('38956', '-', '3896')
```

In the 2nd case, I need it to return `85383` and not `38956-38962`.

Comment: If your goal is to just get the zipcode I'm not understanding your current regex. Why not something along the lines of `\s(\d{5})\D*$`.

Comment: Matching last occurrence is a known and solved problem, `x(?!.*x)`. So, you may just use `\d{5}(?!.*\d{5})`. Or, if there can be no digits after the five digits, you may use JvdV's suggestion.